# How to hide from public and search engine that website is hosted on specific server/host

Tags: vps, hosting

i am working on website, i would like to hide it from general public and search engines.

i have `vps X` , for hosting this site.

and another `vps Y` , which will be front for general public. vps Y will be used as `nginx` `reverse proxying` to `vps X`.

so i dont want people to know about `vps X`. people should not be able to access site directly by accessing `vps X`.

site should be only visible if people access domain name which in turn connected to `vps Y`.

what is the best way to achive something like this ?

---

edit : so far i can think of few ways.,

so far i can think of these options.

1 ) on `vps X`, set website on port other than 80
and do reverse proxy from `vps Y` to `vps X:port other than 80`

2 ) set cloudflare on `vps X,` 
and allow only connections which comes from `clouflare`.
**-aparently cloudflare only works with port 80**

3) on `vps X`, password protect website using `basic http authentication`.
on `vps Y`, while doing reverse proxy pass `username and password`.

4) on `vpx X` check for special cookie, which will be set by `vps Y`, if `cookie` is found then only grant access.
`vps Y` sets cookie to `upstream server` while making proxy request.

Comment: Will vps X and vps Y serve the same data to proper users?

Comment: vps Y is just front using nginx reverse proxy. so data is actually hosted on vps X

Comment: so what's the point? The website will *not* be hidden from the public as long as it's accessible publicly via vps Y.

Comment: its for hiding webhost, on which the website is hosted and possibly hiding the server software which cant be protected using password directly. as the server software doesnt have system like that. think it like elastic search node.

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question to make clear what is your *actual* goal.

You can run a local proxy (apache, nginx, ...) to password-protect access to the app. There's no need to hide the entire VPS

Comment: If vps x has a public IP, just firewall off everything except your front end proxy. As long as the IP is exposed, it’s discoverable, by anybody, and will be discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Simply firewall the HTTP ports on server X such that it only honours requests through serve Y.

You have not advised your OS, but its 2 lines if you can use iptables -

```
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
/sbin/iptables -I INPUT -s SERVER.Y.IP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: server X uses cloudflare for DNS. so need to whitelist cloudflare IPs

Comment: What's DNS on server X got to do with this? DNS is a totally separate protocol.  I can't see why you would need to whitelist these, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: i mean, when connecting to X using Cloudflare , wont cloudflare show every access from their IP address ? thanks. cloudflare acts as a reverse proxy.

Comment: Don't understand what you are saying/asking (or maybe I've misunderstood what you are trying to do).  Surely since the requests are going through server Y the response to the end user will come from server Y without reference to Cloufglare?  (Am I correct in understanding that server X is a VPS on Cloudflares network).